# Deploy node.js app to Azure AppService in DevAzure release pipeline : [error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip<br/>

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Im trying to publish an devlops pipeline to an Azure app service. I've set up the pipeline YAML file and everything seemed to go successfully as the artifact has been published:
[image: run sucess]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Below is the YAML file:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --configuration production
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'dist'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  inputs:
    artifactName: 'drop'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

However, when i try to deploy a release, I get this error on the third step:
Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip
Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE
Below see the release artifact definition and task definition:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Should I maybe update the package or folder field?
[image]

Comment: Hi, you say the error is when you Release, so I think we need to see the Release Artifact definition and Task definition. The artifact definition is mostly just the build pipeline name, but the task definition will likely either include a path to where it expects to find the zip file or it will assume some default defined by the task (which may be wrong)

Comment: 2nd thought: your pipeline is building on Ubuntu but the pattern D:\a\r1\a***.zip is obviously windows specific. That's probably fine if you expect the release to run on a windows machine, but if release is running on linux then hunt down where that pattern is set

Comment: hey @ChrisFCarroll I've updated the question to include more screenshots regarding the release artifact definition and task definition. Also, it is expected to run on a windows machine!

Comment: Alas, I can see nothing wrong :-( The artifact looks okay because it shows that ”latest successful build" confirmation. So that leaves the task definition. On my DevAzure, an "Azure App Service deploy" task has a load more parameters (including path) than your screenshot shows - maybe if you first click on the 'Deploy Azure App Service' it shows path details for that task?

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll, Just added it to the original question. Let me know if you can spot anything! Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @BethMcCoy While selecting artifact in a release pipeline, select the 'drop' folder, click Ok and run the release pipeline. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Azure App Service deploy` task in your **Release** pipeline expects to find a `zip` file (it wants to see a zip file in that "Select file or folder" dialog, not a load of contents).

(MS's `AspNetCore` tasks do the zipping automatically, but you hit errors because you are in `node.js` world where zipping the build output isn't a normal step)

So the simplest fix should be, add an [ArchiveFiles@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/archive-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task *before* your publish task in the **Build** pipeline. After that, your Release pipeline artifact step should 'see' a zip file, and then it might all just work.

NB that final `DownloadBuildArtifacts@0` task in the **Build** pipeline looks redundant to me? It's only the **Release** pipeline which needs to download the artifact again in order to deploy it.

--

Alternative take: Look for a working example of 'deploy a node.js app to Azure App Service'

Most MS examples for Azure App Service are for Asp.Net, in which the publish step creates a zip file by default.

The best I can find is, https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vsts/nodejs/ in which you can see they have the ArchiveFiles task in their pipeline: [image: All the release steps needed for a node.js -> Azure Web app deploy]

*NB they are using a VSTS 'all in one' pipeline instead of the two pipelines (Build + Release) that the DevAzure GUI encourages so you can't just copy their pipeline but you can see what they've got that you haven't got:* the archive step.